# PL/SQL: Concat string in a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to exec a CURSOR in SQL*Plus, but I'm getting this error message :

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small ORA-06512: at line 11

This is my PL/SQL Script :

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cr IS SELECT * FROM LOGICIEL;
    unLog LOGICIEL%ROWTYPE;
    nbrEtoiles NUMBER;
    etoiles LOGICIEL.ETOILES%TYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cr;
    FETCH cr INTO unLog;
    WHILE cr%FOUND LOOP
        LOOP
            etoiles := etoiles || '*';
            nbrEtoiles := nbrEtoiles + 1;
            EXIT WHEN nbrEtoiles >= (unLog.PRIX/100);
        END LOOP;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nombre Etoiles: ' || etoiles);
        --UPDATE LOGICIEL SET ETOILES = etoiles;
        nbrEtoiles := 0;
        FETCH cr INTO unLog;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cr;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that line 11 is

```
etoiles := etoiles || '*';
```

and given the error, it would appear that the string you are trying to build is too long for the local variable you've declared.  For every row in the `logiciel` table, you're adding at least 1 character to the local variable `etoiles` and potentially more based on the value of the `prix` column.  It's not shocking that at some point the string is too long for the variable you've declared.

Comment: Well, I have the type of the `LOGICIEL.ETOILES` column is : VARCHAR2(100), and the value of prix is between 1000 and 6000 so the loop will stop at prix/100 which is a value between 10 and 60, so by adding a character in every loop the maximum possible length for the `etoiles` variable, is 60.

Comment: Given that prix is between 1000 and 6000 the block at the moment will attempt to create a string containing the number of stars as the number of records in logiciel minus 1. You may need check to check you logic; particularly the line: `nbrEtoiles := 0`

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU - It's up to 60 multiplied by the number of rows in the `logiciel` table.  If there are two rows in the table, you'd generate a string up to 120 characters.  Perhaps you want to re-initialize your local variable inside your loop?